# STAX Parser - Inconsistent performance for the same input file

Tags: xml, performance, parsing, stax

I am using STAX parser to process every text node in a xhtml. The application is deployed in Unix box. The parsing operation takes more time the very first instance it is executed. When i run the second time it takes relatively lesser time and in the subsequent calls it takes much more lesser time than the second run with almost consistent results thereafter. Below is the code I am using. Not sure why there is inconsistency in the time taken for parsing the same input. Please help.

One time creation of XmlInputFactory, (static method in the class level)

```
    static {
    if (xmlInputFactory == null) {
    xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    xmlInputFactory.setProperty(javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, false);
    }
    }
```

The parsing code which performs inconsistently giving different response times for the
same input file,

```
    private static void parse(String xhtmlInput) throws XMLStreamException {
    ByteArrayInputStream arrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream      (xhtmlInput.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    XMLStreamReader parser = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(arrayInputStream);
    while (true) {
    int currentEvent = parser.next();
    if (currentEvent == XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS) {
        // Do operation
    } else if (currentEvent == XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT) {
    parser.close();
    break;
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader

Comment: No, that is the API class. What is the _implementation_ of that class -- check out "streamReader.getClass()". It's probably either JDK 1.6 default implementation (Sun's SJSXP), or Woodstox; or if you are unlucky, stax reference implementation... (unlucky since it is buggy)

Comment: This is currently used, com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl. Is there a better one which I should be switching to?

Comment: Yes, Woodstox (http://woodstox.codehaus.org) is the most commonly used one. You seem to be using the default Stax implementation (Sun Sjsxp), which is ok, but Woodstox is typically faster.

Comment: I just realized that the WoodStox factory(class com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory) and XMLStreamReader(class com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader) are used in my code unintentionally. With the jar "wstx-asl-3.2.1.jar" available in my classpath, though I did not have to code differently for WoodStox, WoodStox's Factory and XMLStreamReader instances are created dynamically. So is it just sufficient to have the WoodStox jar in the classpath?

Comment: Yes (see my other comment for details)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing which implementation it is, this is bit of speculation, but there are 2 common reasons why any Java library or application runs faster after a while:

- JVM itself does just-in-time compilation of bytecode, optimizing it on the fly. This is called JIT warmup, and happens quite quickly (over first 10 seconds or so)
- When reading files, underlying operating system usually caches disk blocks being read -- if you read same content again, it is not read from disk but from in-memory disk buffers.

These are also most common reasons why naive java testing benchmarks give useless results: if you do not account for both (i.e. warm up tests for a while, discard initial results; and read test data from memory, not disk), results are meaningless.

Comment: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl is used.

Comment: Ok, that is the default JDK implementation. As per my other comment, Woodstox would be my recommendation.

Comment: I just realized that the WoodStox factory(class com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory) and XMLStreamReader(class com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader) are used in my code unintentionally. With the jar "wstx-asl-3.2.1.jar" available in my classpath, though I did not have to code differently for WoodStox, WoodStox's Factory and XMLStreamReader instances are created dynamically. So is it just sufficient to have the WoodStox jar in the classpath? As you have stated, I believe that the behaviour of the inconsitent results in the intial runs should be due to JIT.

Comment: Yes, it should be sufficient as jar contains META-INF/services entries to 'register' woodstox as a stax impl. JDK default is only used if no other impl is present. Things get complicated if there are multiple add-ons (arbitrary one is used); but with just woodstox it's ok. Would recommend upgrade to 3.2.9 or so tho.